# Положительные делители натурального числа

Tags: java, математика

Здравствуйте! Подскажите по коду?

Выведите на экран все положительные делители
натурального числа и подсчитать количество делителей,
введённого пользователем с клавиатуры.

Код вроде работает компилировал запускался.

1)Правильно ли составлен код на положительные делители?

2)Когда компилируется код выводит следующее:

Вводите ваше натуральное число - 6 //ввел число

Число 3 делится на - 1 3 6 Количество делителей - 3

Как можно сделать, чтобы выводило так:

Вводите ваше натуральное число - 6 //ввел число

Число 3 делится на - 1 3 6

Количество делителей - 3

Как можно сделать, чтобы делители выводились в обратном порядке:

Вводите ваше натуральное число - 6 //ввел число

Число 3 делится на - 6 3 1

Количество делителей - 3

3) Как можно описать код, на ошибку, если пользователь ввел отрицательное число?

4) Как можно описать код, что на ноль делить нельзя, если пользователь ввел 0?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int n;
         int count = 0;
       System.out.print("Вводите ваше натуральное число - ");
        Scanner sr = new Scanner(System.in);
         n = sr.nextInt();
          System.out.print("Число " + n + " делится на - " );
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
           if ((n % i) == 0){
             count++;
              System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
        }
      System.out.println("Количество делителей - " + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: На 0 Вы делить никогда не будете, чтобы пользователь не ввел (посмотрите на **свой** код).

А вот проверить, ввел ли пользователь натуральное число (и сообщить об ошибке (и не свалиться при вводе не числа)) не мешает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В целом можно считать, что правильно. Только единица-то зачем тут? И так известно, что любое число на один делится, и на себя делится.
2. Так допечатайте перевод строки после цикла. Например, System.out.println(); Чтобы их в обратном порядке показывать.. так сделайте цикл в обратном направлении.
3. Так возьмите и проверьте введённое число перед тем как в цикл входить. Подумайте. Как бы вы делали, если бы выполняли поставленную задачу вручную? Вам называют число, а вы в первую очередь думаете, а что вам назвали? Назвали ли вам разумное число? Если нет, то говорите человеку, что он дурак. Если число нормальное, то идёте уже перебирать варианты чисел.
4. Такая же история. Если человек вам говорит ноль, то вы говорите ему, что он дурак. Программа действует так же, только вежливо.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ "cy6erGn0m"

Answer (score 0):

Цикл по `i` лучше вести до `[sqrt(n)]` и выводить делитель вместе с частным (кроме того случая, когда они равны). Резко ускоряет алгоритм при больших n.